# asp.net submit form to itself

Tags: asp.net, forms, postback

I am new to ASP.NET. I have a form with 2 textbox and submit button.
I want o fill out the textboxes and submit the form to itself. BUT as soon as it is submitted to itself, I want the page not to show form with textboxes but a label with "Thank you for submission" to show.
How can I achieve this goal?
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

By checking the IsPostBack property and changing the Visible properties of the controls.